# PuLP CBC multithreading not working with COIN_CMD

Tags: python, multithreading, optimization, coin-or-cbc

I am using PuLP with Python to do some optimization and because my data is so large, I decided to try multithreading as my problem is quite large, i.e. choosing

However, in testing with a small subset of the main problem (10k instead of 1M people), I cannot get multithreading to actually use multiple threads.

I followed [the instructions](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc/blob/master/INSTALL) to build the solver from source using the `../configure --enable-cbc-parallel` flag [as described on Coin-OR website](https://projects.coin-or.org/Cbc/wiki/FYI); everything worked great and all the tests passed. I checked the CBC config log in `build/Cbc/config.log` and it has the message `configure:30105: Cbc multithreading enabled` in line 845, so it definitely is enabled to work.

System:

- Mac OS X 10.14.3
- i7-4870HQ quad-core
- Python 3.6.7 w/Anaconda
- problem occurs both in Jupyter and running in Python interpreter from the command line

Code, similar to [from example here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pulp-or-discuss/IKE--kT6c5U):

```
start = time.time()
solver = solvers.COIN_CMD(~/Cbc-2.9/build/Cbc/src/cbc',threads=8,msg=1,fracGap = 0.01)
prob.solve(solver)
print('time to solve:',time.time()-start,'seconds')

>> time to solve: 24.815305948257446 seconds
```

That time was about the same if I specified the multi-threaded solver or if I just used the default solver.

In the CBC message at runtime was the line:

```
threads was changed from 0 to 8
```

and also the lines:

```
Cbc0012I Integer solution of -25507 found by DiveCoefficient after 0 iterations and 0 nodes (18.04 seconds)
Cbc0030I Thread 0 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.291008, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 1 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.24997687, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 2 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.21034408, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 3 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.17122722, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 4 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.13530493, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 5 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.098966837, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 6 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.062871933, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Thread 7 used 0 times,  waiting to start 0.028151035, 0 cpu time, 0 locks, 0 locked, 0 waiting for locks
Cbc0030I Main thread 0 waiting for threads,  1 locks, 0.00077700615 locked, 9.5367432e-07 waiting for locks
Cbc0001I Search completed - best objective -25507, took 0 iterations and 0 nodes (18.29 seconds)
```

which means that all the threads were created, but not used?

One solution that I've thought of but don't know how to solve: maybe my path to the solver is wrong, i.e. the COIN_CMD solver shouldn't be directed to `.../cbc` but to something else. I haven't found anything on that.

So what am I doing wrong? I couldn't find any other documentation on how to use the threads. Hopefully this is a stupid question with an easy solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hey, is there a tutorial on how to compile enabling the multicore? the link provided doesnt work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks all the work was done during preprocessing. Parallel threads only kick in during the branch-and-bound phase, after preprocessing. Try a model or dataset where CBC has to do some real branching. I.e. where the number of nodes is significant. For most larger MIP models, CBC will need to explore a large number of nodes. In that case parallel threads can make a difference. But in some cases it may also lead to worse performance (see [link](https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2012/11/1-vs-4-threads.html)).

Comment: Okay, thanks! This test was optimizing for 10,000 targets; my real data is about 6,000,000. I tried it with ~750,000 and it ended up using more threads, but like the link (very helpful!) I experienced worse performance.

What I ended up doing was testing ways to manual implement multiprocessing to optimize smaller segments (10,000) at a time with the built-in Python pool.apply method, then combine the results. Optimality suffered somewhat, but only ~.01% but it sped up time massively. Unique to my problem, obviously, but it worked for me.